# Ajax and html events in chrome, firefox and Internet Explorer

Tags: php, javascript, html, select

I have many select elements in a cart, when a select element changes option , a onclick event will be listened to , and an ajax function displayCart will execute.

```
<select name="price">
<option value="peryear" onclick="dispCart('y',2,1100);">1100 Dollar/year</option>
<option value="pertrimester" onclick="dispCart('t',2,300);" selected>300 Dollar/3 months</option>
   <option value="permonth" onclick="dispCart('m',2,120);">120 Dollar/month</option>
</select>
```

this is the ajax function:

```
function dispCart(b,c,price){
   var req1=new getXHR();
   var altr=Math.random();
   var url="cart.php?c="+altr+"&b="+b+"&c="+c+"&price="+price;
   req1.open('GET',url,true);
   req1.onreadystatechange=function(){
   if(req1.readyState==4){
     if(req1.status==200){
        document.getElementById("cart").innerHTML=req1.responseText;
   }
   }
   };
req1.send(null);
}
```

The cart.php is a controller , which connects using some functions to connect to the database , change the cart data ( for example from paiement per month to paiement per year)
then refreshes the cart and displays the new cart with the changes .

the problem is that this cart works great with FF, but with IE and chrome it doesn't execute the dispCart javascript function.

I don't know why???

thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In IE you cannot bind events on the `<option>` element. You should bind the event to the `<select>` element and then find out which option is selected.

[Here is an example using `onchange`](http://awesomerails.wordpress.com/2007/12/04/get-the-value-of-a-selected-option-with-javascript/).

Comment: Thank you friend , I know now where's the problem

Answer (score 1):

Use `onchange` for the `select`, not `onclick` for the `option`s.

Comment: But As you can see, the 3 options have just one common param for the dispCart function (the param that = 2), but how can I transfer the other params to the function???

Comment: Usually people put the data in "value" and parse it out later.